# identify movie about very advanced genetic engineering

Tags: story-identification

I watched this movie around early 2000's. So, maybe this movie is released around late 90's. Here are some scene I remember:

- The protagonist lives in an apartment with a man (maybe his brother). The man/brother is using wheelchair.
- There was a scene in which a geneticist claimed that he could adjust a fetus/baby such as the parents want. Ex: if the parents want a blue eyes, red straight hair and other thing. he could make it happen.
- The protagonist work in a company that launch rocket to space.
- There was a scene in which a police/detective identify a person from his/her hair or skin

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[**Gattaca**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119177/?ref_=nv_sr_1), released in 1997 and starring Ethan Hawke and Uma Thurman.

Comment: Love this movie :)

Comment: One of my favorite scifi films. A must see for anyone interested in genetic technologies.

Comment: I think it's better to post the synopsis/picture/trailer about this film for other people who is interested.

Comment: "there is no gene for fate"

Comment: @Scott Downey, I thought the tag line was "There is no gene for the human spirit"

Comment: @Paul it is, that's a quote from the movie and one of my all-time favourites

Comment: *Gattaca* was often screened at functions for the hemophilia community. I imagine support groups for other genetic disease survivors showed it as well.

Comment: Damn, I did successfully ID it by the headline after all. Ah well.

Comment: You should normally list the things in the question that match the movie. In this case, it's everything. Match on all counts.

Comment: Wow, the trailer makes this film look awful ... which it certainly is not.